# How to return a 404 Not Found page and HTTP status when an invalid parameter of a dynamic route is passed in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

For example, I have a dynamic route `/blog/[article-id]`.

When visiting an existing blog post `/blog/id-that-exist`, it works as expected, and now I want to handle the case `/blog/id-that-does-not-exist` properly.

The code in `/blog/[id].jsx` looks something like:

```
export const getStaticPaths async () => {
  return {
    fallback: true,
    paths: (await sequelize.models.Article.findAll()).map(
      article => {
        return {
          params: {
            pid: article.slug,
          }
        }
      }
    ),
  }
}

export const getStaticProps async () => {
  // Try to get it from the database. Returns none if does not exist.
  const article = await sequelize.models.Article.findOne({
    where: { slug: pid },
  });
  return { props: { article: article } };
}

const ArticlePage = (props) => {
  // This can happen due to fallback: true while waiting for
  // a page that was not rendered at build time to build.
  const router = useRouter()
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>{props.article.body}</div>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = getStaticPathsArticle;
export const getStaticProps = getStaticPropsArticle;
export default ArticlePage;
```

I saw this related question: [How to handle not found 404 for dynamic routes in Next.js which is calling API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168343/how-to-handle-not-found-404-for-dynamic-routes-in-next-js-which-is-calling-api) but I'm not sure if it's the same as I'm asking here, as this does not depend on any external API being used.

Answer (score 2):

**`notFound: true` from Next.js 10**

Starting in Next.js 10, we can do:

```
export const getStaticProps async () => {
  // Try to get it from the database. Returns none if does not exist.
  const article = await sequelize.models.Article.findOne({
    where: { slug: pid },
  });
  if (!article) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }
  return { props: { article: article } };
}
```

as documented at: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

When `notFound` is returned, the rendering function `ArticlePage` just never gets called, and the default 404 page is returned instead.

Note however that `ArticlePage` did get

For some reason in development mode:

- I don't get the expected 404 HTTP status code
- `ArticlePage`, so if you forgot to handle the fallback case, the it might crash due to missing properties

which was confusing me a bit. But in production mode, everything works as expected.

**Workaround before Next.js 10**

As shown https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10960#discussioncomment-1201 you could previously do something like:

```
const ArticlePage = (props) => {
  if (!props.article) {
    return <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
      </Head>
      <DefaultErrorPage statusCode={404} />
    </>
  }
  return (
    <div>{props.article.body}</div>
  );
};
```

but this is not ideal because it does not set the HTTP return code correctly I believe, and I don't know how to do it.

Tested on Next.js 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your answer regarding the solution after Next.js v.10, but I didn't get what was the problem in showing the expected http 404 code during development.

I use Next.JS v.12 and I get the expected 404 normally in development

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring'
import Loading from '../../components/loading'

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
   //your paths

    return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }: { params?: ParsedUrlQuery }) => {
   //get your props
if (!target){
return {notFound: true}
}

    return { props: { ... }, revalidate: 86400}
}

function Index({ ... }) {
    const router = useRouter()
    
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <Loading />
    }
    return (
        <div>
           //my content
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

When the target isn't found, it renders my custom 404 component in pages/404.tsx if I created one or just the default 404 page.

This should work normally during development and production.